# A way to automatically organize #imports in Xcode

Tags: xcode, import, keyboard-shortcuts

I love the "Organize Imports" command in Eclipse to implicitly add and remove classes imported into a source file (as in Java or ActionScript).

Is there a command in Xcode to update the `#import` directives at the top of.m Objective-C files based on the classes referenced within the file?

Comment: How would that possibly work with files that declare multiple classes?

Comment: I want the header file that contains the corresponding class declaration to be imported - which is what I have to do manually now.

Comment: If Xcode magically knew where those classes were declared then you wouldn't need to import anything ever.

Comment: I know, it'd be awesome! That's the type of thing I want from a good IDE.

Comment: As a side note, Xcode offers auto-completion and syntax highlighting for methods and accessors of classes that are not #import'ed, so all the info must be there, right?

Comment: I still can't get my head around why this isn't just automatically taken care of for you. That's the job of an IDE! Now I have to write a script to do this.

Comment: @John - not to mention stuff like *'Remove and Sort'* or automatically resolving dependencies/add imports mature IDEs like Visual Studio do for you.. Xcode's marketing is super-confident they've got the best IDE out there yet it lacks most basic features.

Comment: you could take a look at AppCode, they have auto import.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can do this by creating an Automator action and use that in Xcode as well as everywhere in Mac OS X. To do that, do the following:

1. Start Automator -> New
2. Choose "Quick Action" (or "Service" on older MacOS/Automator versions)
3. add a "run shell script" action
4. use `sort | uniq` as the script and check the "output replaces selected text" checkbox
5. save and give it a name (e.g. "sort & unique")
6. check "Output replaces selected text"

After you saved it, you can just select your imports in Xcode, right click and choose your "sort & unique" action to organize your imports.

This is not as good as the organize import actions in Eclipse or IntelliJ, because it doesn't removes unused stuff etc. but it's better than nothing.

PS: Got that from WWDC 2012 Sessions - Session 402 Working Effeciently with Xcode (starting at 6:15)

**EDIT**

I started using AppCode, the Objective-C IDE from JetBrains, and it has features like "organise imports". You should check it out: http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/.

Comment: In Automator, don't forget to check "Output replaces selected text".

Comment: May not give a solution to the question, but still removes a lot of painful monkey job.

Comment: If you want to make the sort case insensitive, use sort -f | uniq

Comment: @TimBüthe Which of the two would you recommend if one is to start working on iOS development right now? I am already using Android Studio and I simply love that. But for iOS, I am not sure about app code. Thanks.

Comment: @BhargavJhaveri I think the Jetbrains tools are really good. You should evaluate both and decide worth AppCodfe is worth the 199$

Comment: I found that this has the habit of adding a blank line to the beginning of the sorted text, so I use this instead: `sort | grep -v "^$" | uniq`

Comment: "After you saved it, you can just select your imports in Xcode, right click and choose your "sort & unique" action to organize your imports." Poorly explained. Please give more precise instructions. No idea how to do that

Comment: It's called Quick Action now for anyone looking for Services in 2020

Answer (score 3):

I'm resolving this as not currently a feature of Xcode :(

Comment: So 2011 saw the dawn of a new Xcode, version 4. Still no "organize imports" feature. Saddening... I'll keep a tab on this question hoping someone will one day come up with a solution.

Comment: Yeah, although Tim's solution is still worth it I think because it already removes a lot of monkey job.

Comment: @Arrel I think you should mark Tim 's answer as the accepted. Since you asked HOW and he showed you the way

Answer (score 3):

I've found Cedar Shortcuts to at least be usable. It's not as good as Eclipse's import feature (it doesn't organize imports), but it can keep you from having to go to the top of a class file and typing an import statement. With this plugin you just place the cursor on the class that needs imported and press Ctrl + Option + I. Here's the github project. https://github.com/cppforlife/CedarShortcuts

Answer (score 2):

I made a small Xcode plugin to sort the headers and remove duplicates of the file with a shortcut, you can check it out! - https://github.com/insanoid/CleanHeaders-Xcode

Answer (score 1):

[AppCode from Jetbrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/) can do this.

Answer (score 1):

**Swiftlint** has an opt-in rule which if opted, will automatically sort the imports alphabetically.

Add `- sorted_imports` to your .swiftlint.yml file under `opt_in_rules`.

Run `swiftlint --fix` terminal command on project root directory (same where swiftlint.yml is stored).

Answer (score 0):

Yup. Like in Eclipse, this would be an awesome feature since developing in XCode (Cocoa Touch) does require quite a bit of class imports which are not easy to remember and Android development in Eclipse sorts this out with a simple keystroke combination that saves so much time ! Hope there is a way to do this in XCode soon !

Answer (score 0):

[WordService](http://www.devontechnologies.com/download/products.html) (freeware) from Devon Technologies, provides a service that can be used in any Cocoa app that can (amongst others) sort lines.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you  can use an Xcode Extension, such as [Imp](https://github.com/shalamowww/imp)