# Tool which organizes #import in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, plugins, import

There have been some discussions on how to organize your `#import` statements in objective-c. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480666/organize-import-statements-for-objective-c-xcode) tells us how to do it manually and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905347/a-way-to-automatically-organize-imports-in-xcode), we learn that there is no way to let Xcode do the work (like, Eclipse for Java or Visual Studio for C#). Now, I see that, since objective-c is unmanaged, this task is not as easy as for Java or C#, but

*Are there any tools (either Xcode plugin or standalone) that help you cleaning up your import statements? Or more specifically, are there tools that help you with one or more of the following tasks:*

- Adding missing `#import` or `@class` statements
- Removing unused `#import` or `@class` statements
- Converting `#import` statements to `@class` statements or vise versa, depending on what is used
- Changing the order of your `#import` or `@class` statements, e.g. alphabetically or by first usage in your code

PS: Just for the case that somebody thinks that this question doesn't belong here, I guess it perfectly falls under `software tools commonly used by programmers` or `practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession`

Comment: You could write your own: `sed -i".backup" 's/SEARCH_REGEX_^#import something/REPLACE_STRING/' "/path/to/my/project/*.[hm]"`  - http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Comment: For the last bullet point, sorting of your import statements, you can use an Automator action as I described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11178573/60518

Comment: It's a pity it's still not available in 2013 - we've got a good static analyzer, clang, ARC, ... so the IDE understands our code way better than earlier, and still Xcode is lacking basic features of a modern IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AppCode](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/) is the only alternative I can think of that has these kinds of features.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't switch IDEs over such a tiny feature. The amount of time I've spent organizing imports is well and truly negligible.

Comment: I think it's still a valid suggestion. I haven't tested it yet but if you could use it just for that special task and keep working with Xcode, it might worth buying.

Comment: Chuck: It does allow you to use Xcode projects, so feasibly you can just open the project in AppCode, do the transformations you want, and jump back to Xcode. I don't actually USE this tool, just knew it existed.

Comment: Actually, for removing unused #import statements, this works pretty well!

Comment: @Phlibbo: Like I said, if you're spending that much time moving imports around, that seems weird to me. I doubt most developers spend more than 10 minutes a decade moving imports around. If you bill $200 an hour, that time is worth $32 to you. And just launching AppCode once and opening a project would eat up about a quarter of that. I mean, you're welcome to your preferences, but it just seems weird to me.

Comment: In AppCode, `Code > Optimize Imports...`, or `^ + ⌥ + O`.